# How do I rename a script file in Unity yet have Perforce keep its file history?

Tags: unity-game-engine, perforce

I'm working with Unity and Perforce.

I have a script file that's been added as a component, and I want to change the name. Ordinarily, you just change the name of the script in Unity, and it updates referring components.

I know I can move a file in Perforce to keep the file's history, but Unity wouldn't know, so it couldn't update the references.

So the problem is that I want to rename a script in Unity, have its references update, and then I want to tell Perforce about this change, and keep the file's history intact.

My understanding is that the `move` command doesn't expect the file already to have been renamed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not pretty, but you could do it like this:

1. Rename the file in Unity. Unity should update it's references.
2. Close Unity.
3. Rename the file back in Explorer/Finder.
4. Use the perforce client's move command to rename the file again to the new name.
5. Re-Open Unity.

This way Unity references should still be intact and Perforce gets it's move command.

If you have a team license you may also want to have a look at this: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/VersionControlPlugins .

Comment: For reference, we have the P4 plugin (or at the very least, *a* P4 plugin) and it does not use the move command, so history is lost when letting Unity do the rename.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a 13.2 server just move the files ignoring Perforce(no p4 edit or move) and then run either 'p4 reconcile' from the command line or 'Reconcile Offline Work' from P4V. Perforce will automatically see the move and handle it properly.

Comment: +1 This seems preferable to the way suggested by me in the accepted answer as you don't need to shut down Unity this way.

Comment: Hey, I'll try that. But specifically which server 13.2? Perforce?

Comment: But we're using the P4 plugin for assets... it tries to do the move in P4, which I think would preclude this working.

Comment: Can you just turn off the plugin briefly? I sadly don't have a Unity instance with the team extension to try it. 13.2 Perforce server and client are required for the move detection.